# div with position:absolute to overlay on the grand parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a nested div blocks that the inner most div acts as a dropdownlist of its direct parent. The parent is basically a button with a span to display the values selected in the child's dropdownlist.

My problem is that the inner most dropdownlist is hidden by another outer div.
Here is what I have right now: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/movence/z9y2f9wh/)

From the code:

```
.dd {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background-color:blue;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
}
```

".dd" got relative position value to be aligned with other components inside its parent div.

What would be the best way to display whole ".inner-dd" div correctly in the ".main" div (or either ancestors - ".second", ".third")?

Comment: I guess in your fiddle the div is displayed fully right?? I cant understand your prblm. Please elaborate little bit

Comment: 20px of the div(red) is hidden

Comment: I can see the rem 20 px on scrolling. If you want see the entire div u can just remove overflow-x:auto in .second class

Comment: I need overflow-x to get a scroll when the content grows horizontally larger than the size of main div.

Comment: actually i didnt get u.. I still didnt understand your question.. sorry.

Comment: My questions is basically how to display the red area without a vertical scroll bar as in the fiddle.